# Why can't I specify div height in percentage using CSS classes when using jQuery for resizing?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to make the div 30% of the height of the window and then on click make it 90%. The thing is I'm only being allowed to specify widths in percentages but with height it breaks unless its px. Any thoughts? Here's a link:

http://codepen.io/chris86/pen/avvWwJ

Here's the html:

```
<head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>

<div id="button" class="banner" value="Switch Class"></div>
```

Here's the CSS:

```
.banner {
  background-color: #c3c3c3;
  height: 100px;
  width: 50%;
  padding: 0;
  margin:0 auto;
}

.bannerbig {
  background-color: #000000;
  height: 200px;
  width: 80%;
  padding: 0;
  margin:0 auto;
}
```

And the jQuery:

```
$(function() {
    $('#button').click(function(){
        $(".banner").switchClass("banner","bannerbig",'fast');
        $(".bannerbig").switchClass("bannerbig","banner",'fast');
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: if anybody would like to tidy up the formatting a bit that would be appreciated, wouldn't work for me!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The reason your code breaks is because using percentage as the value for height or width is dependent on the height of the parent. As far as the DOM is concerned, the only element that has absolute height / width by default is the document object.

So, you have to specify the first DOM elements which *don't have absolute height by default* as a percentage of the document's height, like so:

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
```

Then use the appropriate percentage heights for your `.banner` and `.bannerbig` classes in CSS:

```
.banner {
  background-color: #c3c3c3;
  height: 30%;
  width: 50%;
  padding: 0;
  margin:0 auto;
}

.bannerbig {
  background-color: #000000;
  height: 90%;
  width: 80%;
  padding: 0;
  margin:0 auto;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks, that worked great, I'll accept in a minute when it lets me :) thanks for describing the problem for me as well, very helpful

Comment: how come it didn't have the same problem with width btw?

Comment: Because by default all elements with `display: block` have a width of 100% of their parent :)